# Adding Amchart Interface to Wordpress API

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, api, wp-api

I'm using the amchart wordpress plugin and want to add support for it via the wp rest API.

Here's what I've done so far:

in ../includes/setup.php
(To $args array I've added:   This will create the /wp/v2/charts route)

```
'show_in_rest'        => true,
'rest_base'           => 'charts'
```

The custom post type is registered in setup.php as:

```
  register_post_type( 'amchart', $args );
```

There are 4 fields in the plugin, and they are all stored in wp_postmeta table

- _amcharts_resources
- _amcharts_html
- _amcharts_javascript
- _amcharts_slug

Attempting to register the rest fields, I've added this to the bottom of the ./inclues/setup.php file:

```
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
        register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_html",
            [ "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    return get_user_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
                },"update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    update_user_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
                },]);
    });
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
        register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_javascript",
            [ "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    return get_user_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
                },"update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    update_user_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
                },]);
    });
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
        register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_resources",
            [ "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    return get_user_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
                },"update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    update_user_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
                },]);
    });
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
        register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_slug",
            [ "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    return get_user_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
                },"update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                    update_user_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
                },]);
    });
```

I've tried passing both of these payloads to the api via ../wp/v2/charts

```
{
   'post_type':'amchart',
   '_amcharts_resources':'resource list goes here',
   '_amcharts_html':'html content',
   '_amcharts_javascript':'javascript content',
   '_amcharts_slug':'slug',
   'title': 'title',
   'status': 'publish'
}

{
    'post_type': 'amchart',
    'title': 'title',
    'status': 'publish',
    'meta': {
       '_amcharts_resources':'resource list goes here',
       '_amcharts_html':'html content',
       '_amcharts_javascript':'javascript content',
       '_amcharts_slug':'slug_testing'
    }
}
```

In either case, the amchart type post is created, but no associated data is being added to the database.  Title is obviously working as it's standard in post_type = 'post', but all meta data is simply not making it into the wp_postmeta table.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution here.

Add this to $args in setup.php

```
'show_in_rest'        => true,
'rest_base'           => 'charts'
```

Add this to the bottom of the setup.php file.
fistly, you're registering the fields to get/set in the rest interface.
then you're registering the specific meta data to the post_type = amchart

```
add_action("rest_api_init", function () {
    register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_html",
        [
          "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                return get_post_meta($post["id"], $field_name, true);
            },
            "update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                return update_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
            }
        ]);

    register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_javascript",
      [
        "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
          return get_post_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
        },

        "update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
          return update_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
        }
      ]);

    register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_resources",
        [
          "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                return get_post_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
            },

            "update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                return update_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
            }
    ]);

    register_rest_field("amchart", "_amcharts_slug",
        [ "get_callback" => function ($post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                return get_post_meta($post["id"], $field_name, TRUE);
        },

        "update_callback" => function ($value, $post, $field_name, $request, $object_type) {
                return update_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
            }
        ]);
});

register_meta('amchart', '_amcharts_html', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true,
  "object_subtype" => "amchart"
));
register_meta('amchart', '_amcharts_javascript', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true,
  "object_subtype" => "amchart"
));
register_meta('amchart', '_amcharts_resources', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true,
  "object_subtype" => "amchart"
));
register_meta('amchart', '_amcharts_slug', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true,
  "object_subtype" => "amchart"
));
```

The valid post body is:

```
{
   'post_type':'amchart',
   '_amcharts_resources':'resource list goes here',
   '_amcharts_html':'html content',
   '_amcharts_javascript':'javascript content',
   'slug':'_amcharts_slug', //or just use the response.id value as the slug if you do not set this explicitly 
   'title': 'title',
   'status': 'publish'  //draft, publish, etc 
}
```